# vertical aligning text within dropdown or text input?

Tags: css, forms, textarea

i have text input and select boxes be at a width of 40px... i want the text within these elements to be in the bottom half of the input field.  I have successfully been able to do this in firefox (but NOT safari or chrome) by setting padding-top: 20px.

i need this to work for safari and chrome however, these browsers seem to auto vertical align the text to the middle.

is there a solution to this?  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your padding code. To make it work in Safari/Chrome/Opera, add line-height: 40px (or any height your field has). All the browsers seem to recognize the padding then.

Comment: i have already tried padding and line-height does Not help with safari/chrome/opera...i am trying to have the selected text in a dropdown in the lower half.. any other thoughts?